# Error installing Joomla 3.5.1 on Wampserver 3.0.4 with PHP 7.0.6

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, wamp

I'm trying to install Joomla on my local machine running Windows 10, with wampserver 3.0.4, PHP 7.0.6 and MySQL 5.7.9

I created a user and database for joomla from phpMyAdmin, but when I get to the database configuration step, I always get this error:
Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Could not connect to MySQL.

I doubled check the credentials and permissions, and even tried installing using mysql root account and got the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you connected that particular user to that particular db ? @Federico Resnizky

Comment: yes, I verified the credentials connecting using the mysql console

Comment: So, you're that db user is assigned to that db. Then check that user privileges also

Comment: Are you trying to use the `mysql_*` database extension? That does not exist in PHP7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double checked my wampserver settings, and apparently now it installs MySQL on port 3307.
I used localhost:3307 as Database Host name and it worked fine.

Comment: WAMPServer does not configure MYSQL to use port 3307 **by default** therefore **you** must have **changed the config**

Answer (score 0):

It's the same on Xampp. I did yesterday some installations. So Joomla! 3.5.1 if with Php 5.6 works but the new plugin for modules on Tinymce editor doesn't work. If with php7 on local sever J3.5.1 doesn't work wery well, also fatal error. I solved on xampp local server with a Bitnami  installation. Perfect.

Comment: WAMPServer can install and switch between multiple versions of PHP so that would probably have helped yo solve this easily as WAMPServer 3.0.4 comes with PHP5.6.19 and PHP7.0.4 and there are ADDONS for PHP7.0.6 and PHP5.6.21